# Unable to get the symbol of legend item in PyQtGraph

Tags: python, legend, pyqtgraph

I have a graph in which the width of the edge is decided based on the size of the node. The nodes represent mails from an IMAP server. I am unable to get the corresponding line symbol in the legend item. The following code runs and shows the legend item description but not the legend.

```
import pyqtgraph as pg
w = pg.GraphicsWindow()
v = w.addViewBox()
v.setAspectLocked()
lines = np.array((244, 66, 131, 255, 1),dtype=[('red',np.ubyte), ('green',np.ubyte), ('blue',np.ubyte),
                              ('alpha',np.ubyte), ('width',float)])
curve1 = pg.mkPen(pen=lines)
legend = pg.LegendItem(size=(10,10))
legend.addItem(curve1, name='0-10 kB')
legend.setParentItem(v)
legend.anchor((0,0), (0,0))
```

It says: "AttributeError:'QPen' object has no attribute 'opts'". Can anyone point out what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: What symbol do you want to add?

Comment: I have 5 different kinds of lines with different widths and different colors. I want to show the different lines with their color and thickness as the legend item. e.g. a line of thickness 2 and color red means a mail of size 10-50 kB.